# What is Type in @nestjs/common ? What is its role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typescript-generics

NestJS have interface Type in package @nestjs/common . but in two days I could not understand its role in detail. Can you help with this?

As an example, I took this article https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#class-inheritance

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/type.interface.ts

```
export interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Short usage example for create Template Class

```
import { Controller } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CoordinateService as S } from "@location/@coordinate/coordinate.service";

export interface Coordinate {
  Id: string;
  longitude: string;
  latitude: string;
  type: string;
}

export interface CoordinateId {
  id: string;
}

@Controller()
export class CoordinateController extends BaseGrpcService<any, Coordinate, CoordinateId>(S) {}
```

```
import { Inject, Type, forwardRef } from "@nestjs/common";
import { GrpcMethod } from "@nestjs/microservices";
import { Metadata, ServerUnaryCall } from "@grpc/grpc-js";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

export interface IProtoData {}

export interface IProtoDataId {
  id: string;
}

export function BaseGrpcService<
  T1 extends Type<Object>,
  T2 extends IProtoData,
  T3 extends IProtoDataId
>(classService: T1): any {
  class BaseGrpcService extends Base implements IBaseGrpcService<T2, T3> {
    constructor(
      @Inject(forwardRef(() => classService))
      private readonly baseService: IBaseService<T2, T2, T2>
    ) {
      super();
    }

    @GrpcMethod(classService.name, "FindById")
    async findById(request: T3, metarequest: Metadata): Promise<T2> {
      return await this.baseService.findById(request?.id);
    }
  }
}
```

When I replaced string "T2 extends IProtoData" to "T2 extends Type" TS sended me error

> error TS2344: Type 'Coordinate' does not satisfy the constraint 'Type'.
> Type 'Coordinate' is missing the following properties from type 'Type': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 5 more.

---

Step 2

What's wrong?

```
class ClassProtoData implements Coordinate {
    Id: string;
    longitude: string;
    latitude: string;
    type: string;
}

@Controller()
export class CoordinateController extends BaseGrpcService<any, ClassProtoData, CoordinateId>(S) {}
```

```
export function BaseGrpcService<
    T1 extends Type<Object>,
    T2 extends Type<IProtoData>,
    T3 extends IProtoDataId
>(classService: T1): any {

}
```

Therefore, I had a misunderstanding of this design. What does it do?

```
export interface Type<T = any> extends Function {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Step 3:

Yes, I understand that I shouldn't use it. I'm trying to understand the mechanism itself. What does this mechanism do?

I understand correctly that type.interface.ts does the following:

1. We take a list of properties described in the interface
2. Inherit the Function object
3. Call the function creation method "new (...args: any[]): T;"
4. As a result, we get not an interface, but an instance of a Javascript function.

Or I'm wrong? I am completely confused with this code.

==================================

ANSWER

EXAMPLE: https://codesandbox.io/s/od6deu

You're wrong. We don't get an instance of a class at all. It's still Typescript, it's all just type values. What the Type type helper is for is to say we expect to receive a class reference instead of a class instance here. Whether that is a class reference that satisfies an interface or a class directly is irrelevant. Think of the imports array in @Module(). We don't pass new AuthModule() to that, we only pass AuthModule and Nest takes care of the rest. That's the kind of thing here. In your example you use forwardRef which should point to another class.That's a class reference

Think of the Type interface as something like newable. We are able to call new Thing() on a parameter of type Type, but do it dynamically.

```
function createClass<T>(classRef: Type<T>): T { 
    return new classRef();
}
```

is valid because classRef is typed as Type. Now if we were to call createClass(AuthService) we'd get an instance of AuthService back even though we passed a class reference, and Typescript is happy with this because classRef is typed as Type and knows it returns T, the instance type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type` is a Typescript type that says we are expecting a class *reference* not a class instance here. This is helpful in places like Nest's `@Module()`'s `imports` and `providers` arrays so that users can pass the class itself without having to instantiate it. Your `T1` makes sense to stay as a `Type<>` because you pass the class reference to `@Inject(forwardRef(() => T1))` which *should* be a type reference. Everything else though, it looks like you need the direct `T2` instead of `Type<T2>` so that you know to return *instances* of that class type (or objects that satisfy the type)

Comment: So when I add the line "T2 extends Type<IProtoData>" does TS convert the interface to an instance of the class? Is it necessary in those situations when any function expects an instance of the class, and not its interface?

I had the same assumptions. But when I changed the code, the error didn't go away.

Comment: When you use `extends Type<IProtoData>`, Typescript is now expecting that you return a class reference, not an instance, that suffices for `IProtoData`. This means not an object with those fields, but an object that can be _constructed_ (i.e. have `new` called) that has those fields

Comment: Below I gave an example where I did it, but the error remained.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you shouldn't be using `Type` for your `T2`. You are returning an actual object with the properties, not a class to be constructed.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I shouldn't use it. I'm trying to understand the mechanism itself. What does this mechanism do?

I understand correctly that type.interface.ts does the following:

1. We take a list of properties described in the interface
2. Inherit the Function object
3. Call the function creation method "new (...args: any[]): T;"
4. As a result, we get not an interface, but an instance of a Javascript function.

Or I'm wrong? I am completely confused with this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll try to think a little more about the details of the mechanism.

Comment: You're wrong. We don't get an instance of a class at all. It's still Typescript, it's all just type values. What the `Type` type helper is for is to say we expect to receive a class reference instead of a class instance here. Whether that is a class reference that satisfies an interface or a class directly is irrelevant. Think of the `imports` array in `@Module()`. We don't pass `new AuthModule()` to that, we only pass `AuthModule` and Nest takes care of the rest. _That's_ the kind of thing here. In your example you use `forwardRef` which should point to another class.That's a class reference

Comment: Think of the `Type` interface as something like `newable`. We are able to call `new Thing()` on a parameter of type `Type<Thing>`, but do it dynamically. `function createClass<T>(classRef: Type<T>): T { return new classRef(); }` is valid _because_ `classRef` is typed as `Type<T>`. Now if we were to call `createClass(AuthService)` we'd get an instance of `AuthService` back even though we passed a class reference, and Typescript is happy with this because `classRef` is typed as `Type<T>` and knows it returns `T`, the instance type

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally fully understood the principle of this mechanism. I could not normally continue to use this design, not understanding what I was doing in the end.